# Changing a domain for a current WP site without having it go inactive

Tags: migration, wp-config, domain, hosting

in doing a project for a client, I was tasked to create a new Shopify store for their current WordPress store (powered by Foxycart).

I've completed the Shopify store now, but the thing is, my client still wants to keep the WordPress site active and assign it a new domain (via GoDaddy) after I assign the current domain to the Shopify store.

How do I back up the old store properly so that I can keep all its info intact?

I tried this [guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-your-wordpress-site-urls-step-by-step/) but I was unable to find a wp-config.php file in the WordPress site. Apart from that, changing the domain via the functions.php file with this code did not work.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );
```

Also, how can I possibly change the domains in a smooth manner without affecting SEO?

Comment: do a migration of the old website for the new domain for example with "wp all in one" plugin or manually. this will give you the old website in the new domain.

Comment: to do only a backup, do it with "wp all in one" plugin or manually coping all the files  in the main directory and make a dabase backup.

Comment: Oh okay, does that work with a Shopify store?

Comment: I am talking about the wordpress website, it seems the old website is a wp website, and in wp its possible to do like this